# Can I detect the press of the collapse button in the NavigationView?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Can I detect when the collapse button is pressed on a NavigationView? (The one on the top of the NavigationView.)
If I can how do I do that?

Here's the code that I use for my NavigationView:

```
<muxc:NavigationView PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" gaze:GazeInput.Interaction="Disabled" x:Name="Navbar" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemInvoked="Navbar_ItemInvoked">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the [PaneClosed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.paneclosed?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) and [PaneOpened](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.paneopened?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) events that are raised when the `NavigationView` pane is closed and opened respectively.

```
<muxc:NavigationView ... PaneClosed="OnPaneClosed">
```

---

```
private void nvSample_PaneClosed(NavigationView sender, object args)
{ ... }
```